# Find the set of all accumulation points for the following set

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Find the set of all accumulation points for the following set.

$$\left\{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{i}{n}; m,n\in N\right\}$$

I am trying to partition the set in a way to find the points but I can not seem to get it to work.

Comment: You may want to say that $i = \sqrt{-1},$ since the letter $i$ is often used as a variable having positive integer values (e.g. summations, indexing a collection of sets, etc.) and thus some people might think you overlooked including $i$ in the condition $m,n \in N.$

Comment: There are some obvious accumulation points. Do you see them? Then prove that there are no other accumulation points...

Comment: would 0 be an accumulation point since 1/m converges to 0? and would that be the only point? @sigmabe